# How to temporarily populate a table with dates between and including 2 date parameters?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, date, datetime

I need to populate a temp table with dates between and including 2 date parameters, let's say start date is 2014-01 and end date is present.

So far, I had managed to do it, but I need only **"year-month" format.**

**Don't need any days involved.**

```
declare @StartDate date = '2014-01-01';
declare @EndDate date = getdate();

;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT @StartDate AS myDate
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(day,1,myDate) as myDate
    FROM cte
    WHERE DATEADD(day,1,myDate) <=  @EndDate

)
SELECT myDate
FROM cte
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

**Actual Results**

```
2014-01-01

2014-01-02
```

**Expected Result**

```
2014-01

2014-02

2014-03
```

Comment: You can string format your date to convert `2014-01-02` to `2014-02` like `to_char(myDate, 'YYYY-MM')`

Comment: @ejazazeem is this the only way?

Comment: @Nae about your solution posted, any chance of modify the code to eliminate days? Only have year-month. Ex: 2014-01; 2014-02; etc

Comment: @DanielDutu Sure, merge it with the conversion in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56966074/how-to-populate-a-temporarely-table-with-dates-between-and-including-2-date-para/56966349#comment100469676_56966074)?

Comment: @Nae and if I merge with this that transform to char is going to join to a same date column format but type datetime/integer?

Comment: @Nae also sorry I am new to this, where should to_char(myDate, 'YYYY-MM') be introduced into code?

Comment: Date datatype can't be stored only as YYYY-MM. Either you store full date and covert while reading or store as text in the required format. You can use [DATE_FORMAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) to format in text. `to_char()' is Oracle's, so discard that in my previous reply.

Answer (score 2):

Replace `day` with `month` as in:

```
declare @StartDate date = '2014-01-01';
declare @EndDate date = getdate();

;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT @StartDate AS myDate
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(month,1,myDate) as myDate
    FROM cte
    WHERE DATEADD(month,1,myDate) <=  @EndDate

)
```

and using the conversion suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56966074/how-to-populate-a-temporarely-table-with-dates-between-and-including-2-date-para/56966349#comment100469676_56966074):

```
SELECT FORMAT(myDate, 'yyyy-MM')
FROM cte
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can I do something to skip displaying the day?

Comment: " 'to_char' is not a recognized built-in function name." error

Comment: @DanielDutu Then you should provide the exact dbms you're using with version.

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2018

Comment: @DanielDutu That's the client program's name to connect to the dbms. Try running `SELECT @@VERSION;`. I've updated the solution for ms-sql btw.